# Having a window with ShowInTaskbar, Topmost, but also a notification area icon

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi

I have a program I want to be able to handle all three states:

1. Not showing in taskbar, acting just as a widget like the Windows sound, network programs etc
2. Showing in taskbar - but not Topmost. The window would still show the notification area icon, and should still behave in the same way as #1, but also show the window in the taskbar.
3. Showing in taskbar with topmost. The window should behave the same as #2, but now the window will show topmost. Note: it should still be capable of being minimised, in the same way that clicking on a taskbar icon minimises a program.

These are my criteria, and I have been working on having them all working nicely together, but I can't seem to get the last few tweaks ironed out. #1 is fine - I have sorted that out easily enough. #2 and #3 cause more issues.

My first question is, how does Windows handle the user clicking on a taskbar icon to get it to minimise/switch back to normal? As I'd prefer to emulate that with #2 and #3.

For #1 I currently hide the window simply by setting `Window.Visibility` to `Visibility.Hidden`. And to show the window, call `Show()` and then `Activate()`.

Like I said, for #2 and #3, I'd like to copy what Windows does when the user clicks on the taskbar icon. Can I do that? Or would I have to find another way to do this?

Comment: Are we talking about one window in the application or multiple different windows?

Comment: @CodingBarfield It's just the one window

Comment: You can't emulate what Windows does, programs are strictly limited in their ability to shove a window in the user's face.  The rules are laid out in the MSDN library article for SetForegroundWindow.

Comment: @HansPassant It's really the hiding of the window in an effective way that's troubling me. For example, I can't use Hide() because it removes the program from the Taskbar. I also can't use Visibility because it does the same thing.

Comment: Minimize the window if you want to keep the taskbar button visible.  WindowState property.

Comment: My issue with that is that I'm changing the notification area icon when the window is Activated/Deactivated. When it's deactivated, it's changed, but that causes the Activated event to fire - which just shows the window again.

Answer (score 0):

1- this is called thumbnail buttons 
[image]
[image]

You can check http://elegantcode.com/2010/12/17/wpf-adding-thumbnail-buttons-to-windows-7-task-bar/ OR http://shareourideas.com/2010/12/19/windows-7-taskbar-thumbnail-buttons-in-wpf/ OR http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699128.aspx

2- there is property called TopMost in the Window class.

3- for the taskbar icon

[image] you can use this library it is easy to use and powerful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22876/WPF-Taskbar-Notifier-A-WPF-Taskbar-Notification-Wi

4- to minimize and maximize you can simply use

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

* that is all the info you need to create your application as you want, if you face any problems read the articles well if the problem still there find where is the problem exactly and ask again.

hope this help...

Comment: Thanks, but I think you've misunderstood the question. I don't want to program the taskbar/make jumplists.